# Best practices of commit() when inserting many rows

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, transactions, database-performance

**[Situation-Aim]**
We have a data-set in CSV of 1 million rows. These need to be imported into a mysql 5.6 database, table with innodb engine, with following columns (matching csv file):
Column1: bigint(15)
Column2: datetime

To import this data, we could use the following python script:

```
#python version: 3.4.3
#mysql connector version: 2.0.4
#Note: this is just a simple example script!

import mysql.connector
import csv

#Set-up db connection
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='secret', database='mydatabase')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

#read/ open csv
reader = csv.reader(open("C:/test.csv", "rt"))

#ignore header
next(reader)

#read CSV and send to mysql
for row in reader:
    id=row[0]
    adate = row[1]
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('%s','%s')""" % (id,adate))

#commit the query
cnx.commit()
```

**[Questions]**
What is conceptually happening when I put the cnx.commit() inside the ***for*** loop as follows:

```
for row in reader:
    id=row[0]
    adate = row[1]
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('%s','%s')""" % (id,adate))    
    cnx.commit()
```

- If I understood it correctly, it is the difference between forcing mysql to WRITE after each iteration opposed to mysql storing everything in its cache and then sending the commit() - write command.
- What are the performance gains/ drawbacks of doing this?
- Are there any conventions/ best practices or practices you adhere to and why?

Thanks!

Comment: A little bit off topic: have you considered usage of [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)? Also read about [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for writing a good question!

Answer (score 3):

You've shown two extreme positions.

One is to commit only after your megarow of insertions. The other is to commit after every row.

Both of these have poor performance. The first is bad because MySQL creates a big transaction, and then at the end has to commit the whole thing. This takes a lot of RAM or temp space.  The second is bad because it commits many little tiny transactions.

The best performing way to do this kind of bulk insert is to commit every thousand rows or so.  But that's just a little harder to program than the alternatives.  In my experience, committing after each thousand rows or so is several times faster than the alternatives, so it's worth the small amount of extra complexity.

Another fast (but brittle) way to do this kind of bulk load is with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, about which you can read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

There's one little twist on your megarow commit: MySQL connections can have an autocommit mode set. In that case your first example is equivalent to your second.  By default that mode is *disabled* in the python connector.

Comment: Thanks for your informative reply. I just wanted to ask you whether you have done or know of any tests that took a closer look at the "every 1K or so". Not that I don't believe you but I'm curious what the 'sweet number' or  'best practice' is. I understand that there are many variables at play that make it hard to answer this question but still :)

Comment: Sequential I/O ~ 128 kb per read/write, random I/O ~ 4kb / per read write. If you have 300 IOPS available and you are writing randomly (mechanical drive), then your sweet spot is something that fits 4kb * 300 in terms of what the drive will write. This is usually much harder to calculate but it's extremely simple to measure - you will have to find out that number on your own since we can't guess how much data each transaction might have and you find that out by brute force importing. Personally, I write 1000 rows per commit when I hunt for performance, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I wasn't doing a performance study when I did that project, I was scrambling to get some data loaded.  I tried 200 rows per commit and 1000 rows per commit. They were pretty close in aggregate rows per minute.  `LOAD DATA INFILE` is much faster than either.

Comment: Batches of 1000 is probably within 1% of the fastest you can get.  Batches of 100 or 10000 may be only slightly slower.  Remember the "parabola" in analytic geometry or calculus or numerical analysis?  And finding the minimum point?  It's somewhat like that.